# How to reliably mount UDF partition with /etc/fstab

Tags: fstab, udf

My HDD

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 927.5 GiB, 995875618816 bytes, 1945069568 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xc4094bc2

Device     Boot     Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1            2048     718847     716800   350M  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
/dev/sdb2          718848  269154303  268435456   128G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdb4       269156350 1945067519 1675911170 799.1G  f W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sdb5       403374080 1945067519 1541693440 735.1G  6 FAT16
/dev/sdb6       269156352  403374079  134217728    64G 83 Linux
```

I have formatted /dev/sdb5 as `udf` with

```
mkfs.udf --utf8 -l UDFStore /dev/sdb5
```

on `Gentoo`. But `blkid` doesn't list `/dev/sdb5`. How can I reliably mount my UDF partition at startup in `/etc/fstab` when device enumeration changes due to additional connected USB devices at startup.

Comment: Does `fdisk -l` shows it

Comment: I abandoned UDF.

Comment: Apart from mounting issues, I faced with sticky files those won't delete and compiling the kernel on it failed.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from device names, you can mount filesystems using their UUID or label.

For example, if when you created the filesystem you labeled it *UDFStore*, you can add an `/etc/fstab` entry like this: `LABEL=UDFStore /data udf defaults 0 0`

Comment: that didn't work. `lsblk` shows no label for `/dev/sdb5`. Stupid of me for voting up without testing. Ur answer felt very obvious! huh!

Comment: Plug in the device, then, run `find /dev/disk`. You'll see paths corresponding to your disks and partitions. Look through the directories `by-label`, `by-partlabel`, and `by-id`. Those are reliable paths, one of which may correspond to the UDF partition. To use filesystem or partition ID's, you can run `lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,LABEL,PARTLABEL,PARTUUID` and match those ID's with the appropriate path from the `find` command above, by looking for device files in the `by-uid` and `by-uuid` directories. Then in /etc/fstab` substitute `/dev/sdb5` with the reliable path of your choice.

Comment: `lsblk` for my udf partition reports no `FSTYPE`,`LABEL`,`PARTLABEL` and `PARTUUID`

Comment: See if this helps: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/35973/udf-and-fstab-no-uuid?rq=1

Comment: Though the solution mentioned there is for entire hard disk, can I still `mkudffs --media-type=hd --vid=UDFStore /dev/sdb5`? Does it destroy data?

Comment: Yes, you can use a partition instead of a hard disk. And yes, formatting the partition again will destroy the data in it.

Comment: Is there a way to set the VID without formatting? Just yesterday, I spent 12+ hrs backing up the data to the UDF partition.

Comment: Try using `udflabel`. Check the man page first, but the command should be something like `udflabel --vid=[yourlabelhere] /dev/[device here]`

Answer (score 0):

> But `blkid` doesn't list `/dev/sdb5`.

That is probably because of blkid cache. Use `-p` to bypass cache and specify also block device. E.g.

```
$ blkid -p /dev/sdb5
```

It should print something like this:

```
VOLUME_ID="UDFStore" UUID="5c587177a6c9eba4" VOLUME_SET_ID="5c587177a6c9eba4LinuxUDF" LABEL="UDFStore" LOGICAL_VOLUME_ID="UDFStore" VERSION="2.01" TYPE="udf" USAGE="filesystem"
```

Then you can use printed UUID to specify your entry in /etc/fstab.