# usb linux format

Tags: linux, linux-mint, partition, usb, usb-drive

I have a Usb drive and that is connected to a laptop running Linux (Mint).

As soon as I install some software in it (USB memory) seems like it recognizes it as a windows partition and doesn't install it properly, or more particularly finishes the installation but there are essential Linux based scripts missing.

How can I format my USB to be recognized as Linux partition?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/45051/format-external-hard-drive-to-linux-compatible-file-system

Comment: Check `parted` or `gparted`. `ext4` will be better if it is a logical partition.

Answer (score 3):

1. Insert USB drive.
2. `lsblk` and find your drive.
3. If mounted then `umount` it.
4. `fdisk` device and create new Linux partition.
5. Format new partition with `mkfs.ext4` or `3` depending on your needs.
6. `mount` drive somewhere in your file-system.

**Note**: Backup your data if you have any before executing `mkfs.ext4`